# Intent is not taking me to the next Activity, instead it takes me to the previous activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

> I have three activities here:
>   -Main2Activity.java 
>   -InsecOnline.java
>   -Login.java

The program starts from the Login page from where it takes us to Main2Activity.
What  intend to do is, create a navigation drawer in the Main2Activity and navigate to different activities using the menu items in the navigation drawer.
In the navigation drawer, I have a menu item called 'InsecOnline Page' on which when clicked, it's supposed to take us to the Activity called InsecOnline. But instead, it's taking me back to Login Activity. I don't get this!

Main2Activity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.inseconline) {
        Intent news= new Intent(this,InsecOnline.class);
        startActivity(news);
    }
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
private static Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}


public void nextActivity(View view){

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

InsecOnline.java

```
public class InsecOnline extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayout layoutProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insec_online);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        layoutProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        //settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("inseconline.org")) {
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                    return false;
                }
                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('col-lg-4 col-sm-4')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


            }
        });
        if(isOnline()) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.inseconline.org/");
        } else {
            String summary = "<html><body><font color='red'>No Internet Connection</font></body></html>";
            webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            toast("No Internet Connection.");
        }
    }
    private void toast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
    private class MyAppWeViewClient extends WebViewClient{


    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.subinasharma.myapp"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.subinasharma.myapp.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.subinasharma.myapp.Main2Activity" />


        </intent-filter>

        <activity android:name=".News" />
        <activity android:name=".InsecOnline"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the whole Logcat:

```
11-22 16:24:36.867 5375-5375/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-22 16:24:37.037 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.subinasharma.myapp-2/lib/arm64
11-22 16:24:37.041 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.subinasharma.myapp, real application class is null.
11-22 16:24:39.902 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.subinasharma.myapp-2/lib/arm64
11-22 16:24:39.936 5375-5396/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.149ms
11-22 16:24:40.402 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-22 16:24:40.604 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-22 16:24:40.680 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-22 16:24:40.798 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-22 16:24:40.799 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-22 16:24:40.851 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so
                                                                              dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so" not found
11-22 16:24:40.851 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
11-22 16:24:40.851 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-22 16:24:43.445 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 54.0.2840.85 (code 284008550)
11-22 16:24:43.657 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
11-22 16:24:43.658 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
11-22 16:24:43.665 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
11-22 16:24:43.665 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
11-22 16:24:43.712 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 13 ms (timestamps 4433-4446)
11-22 16:24:43.712 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "54.0.2840.85", actual native library version number "54.0.2840.85"
11-22 16:24:43.746 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "54.0.2840.85", actual native library version number "54.0.2840.85"
11-22 16:24:43.754 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(151)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-22 16:24:43.772 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
11-22 16:24:44.347 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-22 16:24:47.087 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-22 16:24:49.588 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
11-22 16:24:51.261 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
11-22 16:24:51.488 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5375 SIG: 9
```

activity_main2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you show onNavigationItemSelected method full code

Comment: Check your logcat.. Maybe InsecOnline is crashing and thus will show previous activity..

Comment: can you paste your menifest code here

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: @sunilsunny I think you're right, seems like InsecOnline is crashing afterall. But I don't understand why. Can you help me? I'll update the question.

Comment: Post your logcat..

Comment: You should post your logcat and also your insecOnline activity. It is also possible that you forgot to add InsecOnline activity tag to manifest. As it crashes after you added `finish()` on LoginActivity, then for sure, you have a problem in InsecOnline

Comment: the problem is with your InsecOnline.java activity try to replace with some other sample activity it should work then it might crash inside your onCreate

Comment: @Stephanie-JK Please include the error stacktrace .It is difficult to go through the whole code.

Comment: My Logcat is behaving madly. It's changing like 500 times per second!

Comment: @Stephanie-JK have you seen dropdown in android monitor change verbose to error. then copy it

Comment: Also select "show only selected application" like the image in this page https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Okay, I've updated the Error Stacktrace.

Comment: The one you posted is not the error stack.It's the verbose log. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/3111083 check this link to find the correct reason of error..There will be a line called caused by and which is the real reason for your crash..Or search for Fatal Exception.

Comment: 11-22 16:24:40.680 5375-5375/com.example.subinasharma.myapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-22 16:24:40.798 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-22 16:24:40.851 5375-5631/com.example.subinasharma.myapp E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

This is all it showed this time. Its only an error log and its of the selected application only

Comment: @Stephanie-JK post logcat from line like fatal exception or caused by.

Comment: Can you comment this line  `progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);` and run.I am not sure though if it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your Login.java code:

```
public void nextActivity(View view){

 Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Main2Activity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

And in your Main2Activity.java

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.inseconline) {
    Intent news= new Intent(Main2Activity.this,InsecOnline.class);
    startActivity(news);
}
```

Comment: After I added the finish() statement, the app now crashes after I hit the menu  item (InsecOnline)

Comment: @Stephanie-JK that's what I said ..So it's clear now ,"InsecOnline " is crashing and since you have called finish on Login activity ,the app will show the error dialogue and exit.

Comment: once check you R.id.inseconline thing in menu.xml

Comment: <item
            android:id="@+id/inseconline"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Insec Online Page" />

Comment: paste your main2_activity.xml

Comment: Main2Activity has a lots of xml files.
content_main.xml
activity_main2.xml
nav_header2.xml
All these xml files were created by the in-built NavigationDrawerActivity in Android Studio

Comment: where did you define your NavigationView? that xml i wanted to see